# In woocommerce making an admin invoice where i change the price manually

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

if I sell a product from the backend, not from the shop front-end, I would like to change the price for this order only, not in the product table.

I have searched for variable-price products but cannot find anything that fits my needs.
I found variations and discount rules but I just want to change the price when I make an invoice from the backend, maybe through a dummy product where I can change the description too.

Anyone an idea if this is possible?

With the POS systems I support (Chromis) or in front accounting this is possible.

BTW if someone has a link to a WooCommerce-forum where users help users I would be happy.

Regards,
Jan

Comment: Your question is not clear, however, if you have to make any changes in order, you can edit the order from the backend. Default allowed editable order status are **pending, on-hold, auto-draft**

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the reaction.

I have got an answer from another forum, in Woocommerce one has to enter the order first and afterwords the price is editable.

You cannot see this straight away, first you must put the mouse in the part with the positions, then the pencil to edit appears.

Not the most elegant way but usable.

And i did found more forums.

Regards,
Jan